# Wireshark doesn't distinguish ACSE and MMS PDUs

Tags: wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I am working with Message Manufacturing Specification (MMS) in wireshark. The tool is unable to dissect the ACSE layer. It doesn't show any error but it shows the ACSE data as a part of MMS i.e., after the presentation layer, MMS is displayed. Kindly assist if there is a way for wireshark to distinguish both the layers.

Thanks.

Comment: Suggestion: You might be more likely to get an answer if you post the question at [ask.wireshark.org](http://ask.wireshark.org)

Answer (score 1):

This question is from 2012, but in 2016 Wireshark 2.2.0 is able to dissect ACSE (Association Control Service Element) in MMS PDUs. To test it, you can download [MMS sample capture data from the Wireshark website](https://wiki.wireshark.org/SampleCaptures?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=mms.pcap.gz) and open it in Wireshark. You will see dissected ACSE such as:

```
ISO 8650-1 OSI Association Control Service
    aarq
        Padding: 7
        protocol-version: 80 (version1)
        aSO-context-name: 1.0.9506.1.1 (iso.0.9506.1.1)
        called-AP-title: ap-title-form2 (1)
        called-AE-qualifier: aso-qualifier-form2 (1)
        calling-AP-title: ap-title-form2 (1)
        calling-AE-qualifier: aso-qualifier-form2 (1)
        user-information: 1 item
```